# asp.net returning a view after ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I call with ajax to `NameController\Action`

In this action i return `ActionResult` - a `View(model)`

Is there any way I can redirect the client to the returned view?

Now I see this view only in the fiddeler (as returned content)

Comment: window.location may do the trick but you'll have to return a url instead of the page...

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can redirect the client to the returned view?

Of course, but why are you using AJAX in this case? The whole point of AJAX is to stay on the same page and avoid reloading the entire HTML.

But if you want you could achieve that. For example you could have the controller action conditionally return a JSON result containing the target url you want to redirect to. And then inside the success callback of the AJAX call use the `window.location.href` to perform the redirect on the client.

Let's exemplify:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    if (SomeCondition)
    {
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("TargetAction", "TargetController") });
}
```

and then inside your AJAX success callback:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.redirectTo) {
        // the server returned a JSON result => let's redirect to the target url
        window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
    } else {
        // The server returned a partial view => let's update some portion of the DOM
        $('#result').html(result);
    }
}
```